# Why nmap is slow with Debian stretch/testing with Broadcom BCM5708?

Tags: debian, network-interface, nmap

I had freshly installed Debian testing for a HP G5 server with Broadcom BCM5708 network card.

Nmap scans are about 10 times slower that running on another HP G5 server with different network card.

I had tried nmap on another HP G5 server BCM5708 network card, it is slow, too.

nmap parameters:

```
nmap -T4 10.x.x.x -sV -p0-65535 -v -d
```

nmap shows output like these:

```
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 7.11% done; ETC: 21:04 (0:06:45 remaining)

Increased max_successful_tryno for 10.x.x.x to 1 (packet drop)
```

I replaced the network cable, tried another network port (hp g5 servers has two broadcom network cards).

What can be the problem ?

ifconfig :

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.x.x.x  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.x.x.255
        inet6 fe80::221:5aff:fe4d:a928  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:21:5a:4d:a9:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2687021  bytes 177126339 (168.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 260  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2025533  bytes 132044871 (125.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

dmesg:

```
[    1.392522] bnx2: QLogic bnx2 Gigabit Ethernet Driver v2.2.6 (January 29, 2014)
[    1.872495] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5708 1000Base-T (B2) PCI-X 64-bit 133MHz found at mem f8000000, IRQ 18, node addr 00:21:5a:4d:a9:28
[    2.352441] bnx2 0000:05:00.0 eth1: Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5708 1000Base-T (B2) PCI-X 64-bit 133MHz found at mem fa000000, IRQ 19, node addr 00:21:5a:4d:a9:2a
[    2.354702] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[    2.364238] bnx2 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth1
[    7.878464] bnx2 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware bnx2/bnx2-mips-06-6.2.3.fw
[    7.883425] bnx2 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware bnx2/bnx2-rv2p-06-6.0.15.fw
[    8.012017] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: using MSI
[   11.210980] bnx2 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex
```

ethtools:

```
Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Link detected: yes


The test result is PASS
The test extra info:
register_test (offline)  0
memory_test (offline)    0
loopback_test (offline)  0
nvram_test (online)      0
interrupt_test (online)  0
link_test (online)       0

Pause parameters for enp3s0:
Autonegotiate:  off
RX:             off
TX:             off

NIC statistics:
     rx_bytes: 195197
     rx_error_bytes: 0
     tx_bytes: 20772
     tx_error_bytes: 0
     rx_ucast_packets: 201
     rx_mcast_packets: 0
     rx_bcast_packets: 2563
     tx_ucast_packets: 139
     tx_mcast_packets: 0
     tx_bcast_packets: 0
     tx_mac_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     tx_deferred: 0
     tx_excess_collisions: 0
     tx_late_collisions: 0
     tx_total_collisions: 0
     rx_fragments: 0
     rx_jabbers: 0
     rx_undersize_packets: 0
     rx_oversize_packets: 0
     rx_64_byte_packets: 2440
     rx_65_to_127_byte_packets: 285
     rx_128_to_255_byte_packets: 28
     rx_256_to_511_byte_packets: 11
     rx_512_to_1023_byte_packets: 0
     rx_1024_to_1522_byte_packets: 0
     rx_1523_to_9022_byte_packets: 0
     tx_64_byte_packets: 1
     tx_65_to_127_byte_packets: 83
     tx_128_to_255_byte_packets: 47
     tx_256_to_511_byte_packets: 8
     tx_512_to_1023_byte_packets: 0
     tx_1024_to_1522_byte_packets: 0
     tx_1523_to_9022_byte_packets: 0
     rx_xon_frames: 0
     rx_xoff_frames: 0
     tx_xon_frames: 0
     tx_xoff_frames: 0
     rx_mac_ctrl_frames: 0
     rx_filtered_packets: 123942
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 0
```

netstat -i

```
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
enp3s0    1500     3421      0    245 0           160      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 LRU
```

Comment: What's the name of the "other" network card?  It may be using a different device driver (which may be the reason).  Also, you are using debian testing, so I assume you're using kernel 4.7, right?

Comment: grochmal: other network card /driver is (where nmap is working properly): [    1.080409] tg3 0000:02:02.0: eth1: Tigon3 [partno(349321-001) rev 2100] (PCIX:66MHz:64-bit) MAC address 00:16:35:3c:f3:34.  my new g5 server has kernel version 4.6:  4.6.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1 (2016-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I have read your question 3 times and I can see only one network card identifier: `Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5708 1000Base-T`.  Two such cards, but they're the same.  Under what card `nmap` goes faster?  (slower or faster depend on the observer)

Comment: grochmal: dmesg don't tell the exact type of the card where nmap is runnig fine, only this: eth1: Tigon3 [partno(349321-001) rev 2100] (PCI
X:66MHz:64-bit) . I guess is it is a generic driver for Broadcom.

Comment: You are only looking at the server side;  look at the switch side too.

Comment: Rui: both the g5/broadcom bcm5708 server and the other g5/tigon3 server connected to the same switch. I swapped the ethernet cable other the 2 servers, connected to the same switch. Same result: nmap is fast on hp g5/tigon3 bu slow on hp g5/broadcom bcm5708 bnx2.

Comment: What does ethtool say about hardware offload capabilities (`ethtool -k`)? Have you tried disabling various HW offload features (it may sound counterintuitive but often helps). There are other `ethtool` setting that might help too `-g`, `-c` etc)?

Comment: What is the output of `nmap --version` and `uname -r` on both systems? There is a [known bad interaction](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/34) between some versions of the Linux kernel that results in packet loss like this.